# Script generated image onclick event change

Tags: asp.net, onclick

I have two scripts inside my webpage

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://somesite/somefile.js"></script>
                     <script type="text/javascript" >somecode('a','1z4j73');</script>
```

This script is generating a visitor map on my web page, now I don't want my user to click on the script and get redirect to that website.

How can I restrict that?

can I make a div tag and make all element inside the div tag to read only?

I have make sure that this restriction doesn't falls under company rules, they just want their logo under the map.

**EDIT1**

Can I catch this thorugh any event and again redirect the user to the default page?

Like when user click the image, I check the URL and if the URL contains that site name I again redirect to the default page.

Comment: Can you target the elements by an ID, or do they have a CSS class?

Comment: I have tried by puuting onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to do that?');" this in the script tag, in spite of the warning on VS.. I didn't received any confirmation box when clicking on that image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you create the sitemap for search engine optimization, and would like to keep sitemap links accessible for search engines (indexers), but want to get rid of redirect functionality for visiting users.

If that is so, then all you need to do - is just to assign your own **onclick** function to all links in your sitemap.

```
    // onClick event
    onClickFunction = function ( ) {   
        return function ( ) {
            // do nothing
            return false;
        }
    };


<a href="http://some_url" onclick="onClickFunction();">something</a>
```

or simply:

```
   <a href="http://some_url" onclick="return false;">something</a>
```

this will still work for search indexers, which will look for all `<a>` tags and read **href** value. But because of "return false;" in the onClick event handler function - the redirection for users will be disabled.

Please see this article
http://www.bradino.com/javascript/onclick-return-false/

Comment: I am not getting any onclick event in script tag.

Comment: you need to Set it, in order to disable "link clicking". Its hard to tell how your sitemap is organized (you haven't shared the code). But what I have described - is a basic idea of disabling links for users, and keeping them for search engines.

Comment: I have added a simpler way, and a link to one useful article about this

Answer (score 0):

If you can figure out what the HTML elements are that you don't want, you can remove them using a script library like JQuery:

```
$("#targetelement").remove();
```

Or replace it with your own content.

You don't need a script library to do this though, but it can be helpful to have one.

HTH.

Comment: I tried the same I put the code in the head tag <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#idone").remove(); 
    $("#idtwo").remove(); 
});
</script>

Comment: provided the id to both the script which is idone and idtwo respectively. even now when I clicked on the image I am redirecting to their respective sites.

Comment: Hey, it could be that some process runs delayed and is occurring after your script...  Try wrapping the script with window.setTimeout(function() { .. }, 5000); and see if that makes a difference.